# Cauchy property of weak convergence

Tags: weak-convergence

I found in the measure and integration theory book from Bauer (Remark 6, §20) that if $\mu$ is a finite measure, then the weak convergence of a sequence $(f_n)$ is equivalent to 
$$ \lim_{n,m \to \infty} \mu(\{ |f_m-f_n| \geq \alpha \})=0 $$
for all $\alpha >0$.

It is clear to me that the condition is necessary because of 
$$ \{ |f_m -f_n | \geq \alpha \} \subset \{ |f_m -f| \geq \alpha/2 \} \cup \{ |f_n -f| \geq \alpha/2 \}.$$
But how can I see that this is also sufficient?

Comment: As Bauer writes, check the proof of Theorem 20.7.

Comment: @Siminore Thanks for your suggestion. I already did that and I dont understand how that follows at all from the proof of 20.7, so I didn't mentioned it in my question. Also Bauer indicates that it follows from the second part from the proof - but the proof is not seperated in two parts.